# How to continously profile my go application?

Tags: go, pprof

My application is having some memory leaks which makes the application crash often. So I started profiling my application with pprof, but I can get the profile only at the instance I hit the url. Are there any ways to find the profile at some intervals so that I can analyze what's happening with the application?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/#WriteHeapProfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was hoping that there would be a cool flag to pprof dump on exception (like core dump) but can't find anything.  Pending this there are two options that come to mind:

- External: curl pprof regularly using cron or some other driver
- Internal: write pprof regularly from inside the program

**External**

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/heap > heap.0.pprof
```

**Internal**

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Hour)
go func() {
    for {
       select {
        case <- ticker.C:
if err := pprof.WriteHeapProfile(f); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("could not write memory profile: ", err)
        }

       }
    }
}()
```

---

[The external curl is a strategy I often take in order to get heap profiles at regular intervals in order to track/compare memory growth](https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/sre-debugging-simple-memory-leaks-in-go-e0a9e6d63d4d).

Answer (score -1):

You can use pyroscope https://pyroscope.io/ with pull model. It is scraping your application continuously and putting profiling information to the UI Dashboard.